# Why does the loss of a CNN decrease for a long time and then suddenly increase?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I made a simple network to find broken lines and I had a very strange training run. The loss, keras.losses.binary_crossentropy, was decreasing steadily for around 1500 epochs then suddenly, it shot up and plateaued.

[image: graph of loss function vs epoch]

What are some reasons this happens? Optimizers, loss function, network structure?

I checked the weights, and none of the weights have a NaN value. The input data is 250,000+ 32x32 images with lines on them, and the same stack of images where the lines have a few pixels removed from so they're "broken".

[image: sample solid lines and broken lines]

Here is the model creation code:

```
input_shape = (1, 32, 32)
kernel_shape = (16, 16)
keras.backend.set_image_data_format("channels_first")
n_filters = 64
input_layer = engine.Input(input_shape)
active_1 = layers.Activation("relu")(input_layer)
conv_1 = layers.Conv2D(n_filters, kernel_shape)(active_1)
conv_2 = layers.Conv2D(2*n_filters, kernel_shape)(conv_1)
pool_1 = layers.MaxPooling2D()(conv_2)

s = tupleFromShape(pool_1.shape)
p = 1
for d in s:
    p *= d

shaped_1 = layers.Reshape((p,))(pool_1)
dense_1 = layers.Dense(2)(shaped_1)
out = layers.Activation("softmax")(dense_1)
model = engine.Model(input_layer, out)
model.save("broken-lines-start.h5")
```

And the training code:

```
full = #numpy array (c, slices, 32, 32)
broken = #numpy array(c, slices, 32, 32)
full = full[0]
broken = broken[0]

n = len(full) - 1024
n2 = len(broken) - 1024

random.shuffle(full)
random.shuffle(broken)

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(0.00001)
loss_function = keras.losses.binary_crossentropy
model.compile(
        model, 
        optimizer, 
        loss_function=loss_function)
batch_size = 256
steps = n//batch_size + n2//batch_size
model.fit_generator(generator=getDataGenerator(full[:n], broken[:n2], batch_size),
                steps_per_epoch=steps,
                epochs=4680,
                validation_data=getDataGenerator(full[n:], broken[n2:], batch_size),
                validation_steps=2048//batch_size,
                callbacks=[saves_last_epoch_and_best_epoch]
                    )
model.save("broken-lines-trained.h5")
```

The generator code:

```
def getDataGenerator(solid, broken, batch_size=128):
    zed = [([chunk], [1, 0]) for chunk in solid] + [([chunk], [0, 1]) for chunk in broken]
    random.shuffle(zed)
    xbatch = []
    ybatch = []
    while True:
        for i in range(len(zed)):
            x,y = zed[i]
            xbatch.append(x)
            ybatch.append(y)
            if len(xbatch)==batch_size:
                yield numpy.array(xbatch),numpy.array(ybatch)
                xbatch = []
                ybatch = []
```

I have greatly improved this model, and it hasn't exhibited this behavior yet, but I would like to understand why this happened.

Subsequent things I have tried:

Change the loss function to logcosh -> works

Change the epsilon value of the adam optimizer -> still blows up.

Change the optimizer to SGD -> blows up faster, didn't have initial decrease.

Comment: I don't get how this is too broad. The problem is very specific. I trained the network for a long time and it blew up. I don't know what causes this. I aslo included all of the specifics so somebody can reproduce the problem if they want.

Comment: Out of curiosity @matt, why did you set `kernel_shape = (16, 16)`?

Comment: @fromkerasimportmichael Also out of curiosity, I was trying to explore the effects of kernel size and understand what is happening. I switched to a smaller kernel (5,5) and had much better results. Possibly even a smaller would work in this case since I can find broken lines with a 3x3 region.

Comment: When I have had this sort of behaviour @matt, my intuition (which may be 100% wrong) was that it occurred because I set up something that was making it difficult for the network to learn (poor hyperparameters or structure). The network struggles for a bit, but it's just a matter of time until it heads off down the wrong path and explodes. I wondered if your large kernel size might be making it difficult for the network to learn (small signal in a big kernel, signal gets even smaller as it progresses though other layers, etc). Again, just intuition, not anything I'd bet my own money on.

Answer (score 3):

One of the possible issues might be with the **Adam** optimizer -- it is known to "explode" when you train it for a long time.

Let's look at the formula of **Adam** (sorry for the ugly presentation, may change to beautiful LaTeX later):

```
t <- t + 1
lr_t <- learning_rate * sqrt(1 - beta2^t) / (1 - beta1^t)

m_t <- beta1 * m_{t-1} + (1 - beta1) * g
v_t <- beta2 * v_{t-1} + (1 - beta2) * g * g
variable <- variable - lr_t * m_t / (sqrt(v_t) + epsilon)
```

where `m` and `v` are estimates of the first moment (the mean) and the second moment (the uncentered variance) of the gradients respectively. When you trained the model for a long time, `v` can become very small.

By default, according to [tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer), `beta1=0.9` and `beta2=0.999`. So `m` changes more quickly than `v`. So `m` can start being big again while `v` cannot catch up. This will result in a large number dividing by a very small value and explode.

Try to increase the `epsilon` parameter, which is `1e-08` by default. Try experimenting with values like `0.01`, or `0.001`, depending on your model.

Comment: This is some good information to know. Aside for re-running the model, do you know a good way to verify this?  I am re-running the model though to check it out.

Comment: After re-running the model keeping everything the same except for the epsilon value, it still blows up. So far, changing the loss function has prevented it from blowing up.